# Include with where condition , but keep all result before including

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am having a problem in querying inside the include

What I do is

```
    const courses = await Course.findAll({
    subQuery: false,
    order: [ [ 'courseID', 'ASC' ] ],
    include: [
        {
            model: CourseAvailable,
            as: 'courseAvailable',
            where: {
                id: 350 // dummy condition only for asking here ( I had my purpose )
            }
        }
    ]
    });
```

and the output

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 20,
        "courseID": "MTH102",
        "courseName": "MATHEMATICS II",
        "required": "{MTH101}",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "courseAvailable": [
            {
                "id": 350,
                "courseID": "MTH102",
                "semester": 2,
                "credit": 3,
                "totalSeat": 150,
                "section": "7",
                "allowedGroup": "EET 1 A(0)",
                "day": "จ.",
                "start": "10.30",
                "end": "12.30",
                "classroom": "CB1103",
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T15:22:50.176Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T15:22:50.176Z"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the output, I know that querying inside the include will only return the courses that found with the query inside the include ( as you can see there is only 1 Course in the returned data )

But I still want to query inside the include to make the include show only if it meets my condition ( like filtering the include )

**But the thing is I still want to keep my other courses also which doesn't meet any condition**

Expected Output

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 19,
        "courseID": "MTH101",
        "courseName": "MATHEMATICS I",
        "required": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "courseAvailable": [] // showing empty array if none has met my query => still keep the data above
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "courseID": "MTH102",
        "courseName": "MATHEMATICS II",
        "required": "{MTH101}",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T17:30:44.085Z",
        "courseAvailable": [
            {
                "id": 350,
                "courseID": "MTH102",
                "semester": 2,
                "credit": 3,
                "totalSeat": 150,
                "section": "7",
                "allowedGroup": "EET 1 A(0)",
                "day": "จ.",
                "start": "10.30",
                "end": "12.30",
                "classroom": "CB1103",
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T15:22:50.176Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T15:22:50.176Z"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using where inside an include, Sequilize will perform an inner join, as mentioned [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#nested-eager-loading). You would need to set the attribute `required: false` inside your include to perform a left join. Change your query to

```
const courses = await Course.findAll({
    subQuery: false,
    order: [ [ 'courseID', 'ASC' ] ],
    include: [
        {
            model: CourseAvailable,
            as: 'courseAvailable',
            where: {
                id: 350 // dummy condition only for asking here ( I had my purpose )
            },
            required: false
        }
    ]
    });
```

Comment: This answered my question, thanks a lot. I thought I was doing that before but I might have put it somewhere in the wrong place